# How to find maximum pixel intensity of the two regions obtained after finding the threshold of the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, grayscale, threshold

We are working on DIP project where we found out the threshold of the gray scale image. Now we have to * find the maximum intensity of the two regions that we got, one region whose pixels are less than the threshold and the other whose pixels are greater than it. *
PS. We are not converting the image into binary image after finding the threshold. We just have to separate pixels in two regions and find the maximum intensity in each region 
PS: We are working on MATLAB

Comment: How about going over the image pixel by pixel and then having if statements to search for the maximum in each region?

Comment: This is a great question, but what language(s) are you using? What platforms? Please update your tags in your question.

Comment: I got the maximum intensity.Thanks.!
  I have to find the coordinates of the two maximum values that I got. But as I have more than one value at maxAbove and maxBelow, so instead of getting one particular coordinate, I'm getting a vector of coordinates. I just want one particular coordinate. How to do that?     I'm working on matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is pretty simple to do.

Here is a function to do so:

```
function [ lowThrMaxIntns, highThrMaxIntns ] = FindMaxIntnesity ( mInputImage, thrLevel )

% Pixels which are lower than the threshold level
mLowThrImage    = zeros(size(mInputImage));
% Pixels which are higher than the threshold level
mHightThrImage  = zeros(size(mInputImage));

mLowThrImage(mInputImage < thrLevel)    = mInputImage(mInputImage < thrLevel);
mHightThrImage(mInputImage >= thrLevel) = mInputImage(mInputImage >= thrLevel);

[lowThrMaxIntns lowThrMaxIntnsIdx]      = max(mLowThrImage(:));
[highThrMaxIntns highThrMaxIntnsIdx]    = max(mHightThrImage(:));

end
```

The output are only the intensities of the pixels.
If you need the pixel location, use the `Idx` variables (Use `ind2sub` for the sub scripts form).

Comment: Thanks.! I got the max and min intensities. but the thing is there are more than one coordinates having that particular maximum intensity. But i'll be needing just one coordinate to work with. 
PS: My project is such that I have to find the pixel intensity of the original image at those two coordinates of the maximum values which I got from the gray scale image. @drazick

Comment: I didn't understand, is there a problem with the code?

Comment: Hey.! @Drazick. I got the code working. Thanks. No there is no problem in the code.
Thanks again.. :)

Comment: By the way, come and join us for dedicated forum for Image Processing: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision Just up vote questions with low voting (Less than 10). Thank You.